# Navigation drawer with curverd edge in android

Tags: android, layout, material-design, navigation-drawer

I have done different Navigation Drawer types like Permanent,Persistent
Mini variant,Temporary.

All of them are rectangle in their outline shape like below.

[image]

---

**Requirement**: I want to create a Navigation Drawer with a curved edge(in its right side).

[image]

Let's have a look on my nav. view

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
```

It contains  `app:headerLayout` and a `app:menu`. If I can change the parent `NavigationView` edges those `app:headerLayout` and `app:menu`will be displayed inside it's parent boundaries. Am i right ?

Change of the `android:background` didn't work for me.

---

What about adding `dimen` in `dimens.xml` is there any attribute that I can use?

Is it possible to curve Navigation Drawer's edge (programmatically or using an image)?

If yes any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Btw this is not a project requirement i am just interested in it..so i am not in a hurry.. will be great to create that kind of a navigation! Isn't it?If you have an idea feel free to share the knowledge :))

Comment: There is one beautiful library, that has curved edge effect while opening the drawer, but not static:) Maybe it would be interesting for you https://github.com/mxn21/FlowingDrawer

Comment: @rom4ek  ill give it a try Thanks :))

Comment: this also may helps you https://github.com/mzule/FantasySlide

Comment: @MilapTank  That's kind of same as i asked instructions are in another lang.. ill try it for sure ..Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally, I've decided to create library for this case: https://github.com/rom4ek/ArcNavigationView, feel free to explore and use it:) It's based on [Florent Champigny's ArcLayout](https://github.com/florent37/ArcLayout), with some adjustments, thanks to him.

The advantage of this lib over suggested is that it was built **on top** of standard `NavigationView` from android design library, and you can use it as usual, just change the classname. Hopefully, will be published on **jcenter** soon. Here are some screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Thanks for the idea! :)

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer,Even before test it for the work-you have done you deserve more than a bounty :)) Thank  you too

Comment: rom4ek and @Charuක I want to do rounded corners instead of the edge, when I tried to add a shape only the bottom is round but the top isn't so I am not quite sure how to have that eff

Answer (score 6):

This Lib may helps you

> https://github.com/mzule/FantasySlide

How to Use: XML

```
<com.github.mzule.fantasyslide.FantasyDrawerLayout   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/fake" />// this image is part of home scren 

<com.github.mzule.fantasyslide.SideBar
    android:id="@+id/leftSideBar"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:maxTranslationX="66dp"> // This attribute is for curve  

    <!--  SideBar  -->

</com.github.mzule.fantasyslide.SideBar>
```

JAVA:

```
SideBar leftSideBar = (SideBar) findViewById(R.id.leftSideBar);
leftSideBar.setFantasyListener(new SimpleFantasyListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onHover(@Nullable View view) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onSelect(View view) {
     return false;
   }

  @Override
   public void onCancel() {
  }
});
```

Comment: is that image view helped to create the drawer ? any way to get custom shapes there by adjusting an attribute?

Comment: Which Image? you are asking ?

Comment: @drawable/fake one ,in anyways i like that one +1

Comment: drawable/fake  is for home screen its not part of SideBar

Comment: Look at this Example https://github.com/mzule/FantasySlide/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml

Comment: yeah i see an attribute called `app:maxTranslationX="-33dp"` woah need to test this :))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133050/discussion-between-milaptank-and-charuka).

Answer (score 2):

According to me, to achieve this you will have to make your own custom class extending ViewGroup (or FrameLayout) like we have in DrawerLayout class.

EX:

```
public class DrawerLayout extends ViewGroup implements DrawerLayoutImpl {
/*
..
*/
}
```

In your custom class, you can use Canvas and Paint to draw your preferred shape. You can override the methods implement it in your way.

Then you can use it inside your Activity:

```
MyDrawerLayout drawer = (MyDrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_drawer_layout);
```

In your activity_file.xml :

```
<com.yourpackage.MyDrawerLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- .... -->

</com.yourpackage.MyDrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this from above library :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
<com.rom4ek.arcnavigationview.ArcNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    app:itemBackground="@android:color/white"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:arc_cropDirection="cropInside"
    app:arc_width="96dp"/>
```